# map a data from a list into a property of a new object list in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to take a list of IDs and put them into a property of a new object list. I'm not quite sure how to do this efficiently.

```
public class User {
   @JsonProperty("Id")
   private long id;

   @JsonProperty("Username")
   private String username;

   @JsonProperty("Enable")
   private boolean enable;

   // Getters/Setters
}
```

```
   public void enableUsers(List<Long> userIds) {
      List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
      ids.stream().map(???).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

I'm not really sure what to do here.  I suppose the equivalent in a foreach loop would be:

```
   public void enableUsers(List<Long> userIds) {
      List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
      for (long useId : userIds) {
         User user = new User();
         user.setId(userId);
         users.add(user);
      }
   }
```

Comment: If you have constuctor use like _.map(id -> new User(id))_ or just use multiple statement  like _.map(id -> {...})_

Comment: An equivalent to the foreach would be something like `List<User> users = ids.stream().map(id -> { User u = new user(); u.setId(id); return u;}).collect(Collectors.toList());`. You should probably pass the id to the constructor thus it would become `map(id -> new User(id))`. Also note that if creating/getting a user is a more complex process (like a db lookup) then doing it in a stream is probably not the right approach.

Comment: with a constructor that takes only `id` you can also do `.map(User::new)`

Answer (score 0):

You can collect these id's in user object using stream shown as below:

```
    public void enableUsers(List<Long> userIds) {
          List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
          userIds.stream().map(id -> {
          User user = new User();
          user.setId(userId);
          return user;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
       }
```